# Parameterized derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have 3 data points: $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)$

$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are fixed values.
$y_1,y_2,y_3$ are all separate functions of a third variable, $t$

So:
$y_1=f_1(x,t)$
$y_2=f_2(x,t)$
$y_3=f_3(x,t)$

At any given $t$, I can fit a curve through these three data points (spline, Bezier or whatever):
$y=f(x)$, so $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be calculated for any $x$.

What is $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at any value of $x$?

Comment: You don't have enough information, or your problem does not clearly states what you know. What's missing is what's the relationship between $x$ and $f_i$ and $t$.

Comment: $x$ is not a function of $t$, it is an independent variable.

Comment: Do you know the functions $f_i$? Say $f_i(t)=t^i$. What is supposed to be $y$ in between? Where does this problem comes from?

Comment: I do know the functions $f_i$.  $y$ in between is calculated from the spline curve fit.  The problem is a curve fit of a 2d graph. That works, now I need the derivatives.

Comment: @Andrei thanks... a reply to my response above would have been more helpful

Comment: I did not vote down the question. I am still thinking about it. I think I have a solution

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fit the data through 3 points is to draw a quadratic $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
In this case, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are also depending on a parameter $t$:
$$y(x,t)=a(t)x^2+b(t)x+c$$
You are not given $a(t)$, $b(t)$, and $c(t)$ directly, so you need to calculate them. What you have is a system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}ax_1^2+bx_1+c=y_1=f_1(t)\\ax_2^2+bx_2+c=y_1=f_2(t)\\ax_3^2+bx_3+c=y_3=f_3(t)\end{cases}$$
You can solve this in terms of unknowns $a$, $b$, $c$ using determinants:
$$a(t)=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
f_1(t) & x_1 & 1 \\ 
f_2(t) & x_2 & 1 \\  
f_3(t) & x_3 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\ 
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\  
x_3^2 & x_3 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{f_1(t)\begin{vmatrix}
 x_2 & 1 \\  
 x_3 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}-f_2(t)\begin{vmatrix}
 x_1 & 1 \\  
 x_3 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}+f_3(t)\begin{vmatrix}
 x_1 & 1 \\  
 x_32 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\ 
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\  
x_3^2 & x_3 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}}$$
You get a similar expression for $b(t)$ and $c(t)$.
Taking derivative with respect to time should be easy now:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{da(t)}{dt}x^2+\frac{db(t)}{dt}x+\frac{dc(t)}{dt}$$

Comment: Thanks yes this is a solution.  Actually I made an error in simplifying my real world problem.  Actually $x$ is a function of $t$, $y$ is not.  In the end I formed a 2-d spline and then used the chain rule to get $\cfrac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$